# django :signals is not working pre_save()

Tags: python, django

I have user app.

In signals.py I have

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from user.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
import random
import string

@receiver(pre_save,sender=User)
def create_hash_for_user(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    allowed_chars = ''.join((string.ascii_letters, string.digits))
    unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for _ in range(32))
    print("Request finished!")
    instance.user_hash = unique_id
    instance.save()
```

In apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'user'

    def ready(self):
        import user.signals
```

In models.py
I have extended the abstractbaseuser

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
        AbstractBaseUser,
        BaseUserManager
    )

from .utils import file_size

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username,email,password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username,email,password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True,validators=[file_size])
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_hash = models.CharField(max_length=512,blank=True,null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD='email'

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

But signal function is not called, and Request finished! is not printed and user_hash is not created.

Comment: I think you don't have to save() your instance. What happend after remove `instance.save()` line?

Comment: @seuling nothing happens, just normal save happens, but user_hash doesnot have value

Comment: Weird. Can you upload your user model? I guess it's not the signal's problem. Or you can add other signal for testing.

Comment: @seuling I have updated my question.

Comment: Did you add `default_app_config = 'user.apps.UserConfig'`?

Comment: Also, you should remove `instance.save()` for pre_save - it will cause recursion

Comment: @seuling Addin 'user.apps.UserConfig' in __init__.py shows recursion error in the admin

Comment: Yes you should remove `instance.save()` - your instance saved after pre_save process so you don't have to save it.

Comment: @seuling  I tried it, no change

Comment: I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Furthurmore, I recommend change to `post_save`, not `pre_save`

In your code, each user make there own user_hash for every save() method for user. I guess you didn't intend this.

`user_hash` have to created only right after creation. So you can use `post_save` with `created` command. Like this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_hash_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        allowed_chars = ''.join((string.ascii_letters, string.digits))
        unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for _ in range(32))
        print("Request finished!")
        instance.user_hash = unique_id
        instance.save()
```

Or, you should check your instance have `pk` before add user_hash. Like this

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=User)
def create_hash_for_user(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:
        allowed_chars = ''.join((string.ascii_letters, string.digits))
        unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for _ in range(32))
        print("Request finished!")
        instance.user_hash = unique_id
```

Comment: Which error message did you get? I made my test app and it works both.

Answer (score 5):

In your `__init__.py` of user app, you must set the app config you created in `apps.py`

```
# __init__.py
default_app_config = 'user.apps.UserConfig'
```

Comment: I wish I could give you a million upvotes. Wasted hours to make the post_save work.